# Javascript: Add Dynamic Text to Markdown

Tags: javascript, markdown, line-breaks

I have some markdown content. For example:

```
let text = `This is line one,

This is para 2

![Tux, the Linux mascot](/assets/images/tux.png)

**This is title 1**

This is para 3

**This is title 2**

This is para 4`
```

What I need to do is add a string like  inbetween this markdown, after the 4th line break. So, it should appear after Title 1, and the new markdown should look as follows:

```
`This is line one,
    
 This is para 2
    
 ![Tux, the Linux mascot](/assets/images/tux.png)
    
 **This is title 1**
    
 <Ad />

 This is para 3
    
 **This is title 2**
    
 This is para 4`
```

The problem is that I don't know how to look for line breaks in javascript.

How can I do this in javascript? The result should still be valid markdown.

Comment: If you are using the new ES6 `\`` syntax, then it will respect the line breaks and you can find it by searching for `\n` in your code

Comment: `const arr = text.split(/\r?\n/);
console.log(arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string by line breaks.

Then loop through the elements in the array, and then add the text after the nth element.

```js
let text = `This is line one,

This is para 2

![Tux, the Linux mascot](/assets/images/tux.png)

**This is title 1**

This is para 3

**This is title 2**

This is para 4`;

let split = text.split(/\n/g).filter(function(el) {
  return el;
})

let newString = '';

split.forEach(function(value, key) {
  if (key == 3) {
    newString += value + '\n\n' + '<Ad />\n\n';
  } else {
    newString += value + '\n\n';
  }
});

console.log(newString)
```

Comment: Since this answer is better imo, I removed mine. I will still past the code that search for break lines without regex: `content.replace("\n", "\nAdvertisment \n");`. In here we are completing each break lines `\n` with additional text.

Comment: @mwryl how would you change let split = text.split(/\n/g).filter(function(el) {
  return el;
}) to without regex? Or haven't I understood what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet allows you to insert some `insert` string immediately after the line (only non-blank lines are considered) specified by `insertAfter` index. Without looping.

```js
const input = `This is line one,

This is para 2

![Tux, the Linux mascot](/assets/images/tux.png)

**This is title 1**

This is para 3

**This is title 2**

This is para 4`;

const insert = '\n\n<Ad />';
const insertAfter = 3;

const match = input.matchAll(/\S\n/g);
const position = Array.from(match)[insertAfter].index + 1;

const output = [input.slice(0, position), insert, input.slice(position)].join('');

console.log(output);
```